# Entity Framework Code First and WebMatrix membership

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-membership, entity-framework-migrations

I started a new project with EntityFramework 5.0 Code First with Automatic Migration and MVC4 with Simple Membership.

And I modified the Configuration.cs with the following:

```
        protected override void Seed(UsersContext context)
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "UserID", "Username", true);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Initialized websecurity");
            CreateUser("admin");
            CreateUser("radu");
            CreateUser("mariana");
        }

        private static void CreateUser(string username)
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.UserExists(username))
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, "123456");
            }
            else
            {
                Membership.DeleteUser(username);
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, "123456");
            }
        }
```

Web.config entries look like this :

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider"
             type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Error message: The user name or password provided is incorrect.

Unfortunately after a successfully migration when I try to log in with one of the users inserted in db, I get invalid log in message. Why is that and how should I fix this?

Comment: Can you please post the error message you are getting

Comment: User account and password don't match. Password is somehow bad. Please check the update of the q.

Comment: Do you have a connection string configured?

Comment: Yes, If I start the website and create a new account with same password, then I can login with the password I provided: 123456

Comment: Are you trying to login from the same website as the one you created the seed value from?  Ie, are you sharing the same database with a production and development website instance?

Comment: @MystereMan thanks for pointing this out, I had some changes between the two inits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problems:

```
protected override void Seed(Handmade.Web.Models.UsersContext context) {
    if (!WebSecurity.Initialized) {
        //WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "UserID", "Username", true); 
        // I used wrong init for seed method
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Initialized websecurity");
    CreateUser("admin");
    CreateUser("radu");
    CreateUser("mariana");
}

private static void CreateUser(string username) {
    if (!WebSecurity.UserExists(username)) {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, "123456");
    } else {
        Membership.DeleteUser(username);
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, "123456");
    }
}
```

Also corrected init from the filter attribute I used:

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                //Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

                try
                {
                    using (var context = new UsersContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }
                    }

                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```